# Inconveniente para logearse en proyecto laravel

Tags: php, laravel, login

El formulario no me esta dejando pasar porque supuestamente los datos ingresados no son validos. Pero ingreso los que tengo en la BD y sigue con el error.

Esta es la captura que me sale al ingresar los datos. Tampoco he podido mover el mensaje de error abajo del input para que no me tape parte del input.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

vista formulario **login.blade.php**

```
@extends('auth.contenido')

@section('login')
<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="card-group mb-0">
            <div class="card p-4">
                <form class="form-horizontal was-validated" method="POST" action="{{route('login')}}">
                    {{csrf_field()}}
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h1>Acceder</h1>
                        <p class="text-muted">Control de acceso al sistema</p>
                        <!--si el usuario no es correcto, se hace la expecion en este input-->
                        <div class="input-group mb-3 {{$errors->has('usuario' ? 'is-invalid': '')}}">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon-user"></i></span>
                            <input type="text" value="{{old('usuario')}}" name="usuario" id="usuario" class="form-control" placeholder="Usuario">
                            <!--se muestra el mensaje del error-->
                            {!!$errors->first('usuario','<span class="invalid-feedback">:message</span>')!!}
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group mb-4 {{$errors->has('password' ? 'is-invalid': '')}}">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon-lock"></i></span>
                            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control"
                                placeholder="Password">
                            {!!$errors->first('password','<span class="invalid-feedback">:message</span>')!!}
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-6">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary px-4">Acceder</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="card text-white bg-primary py-5 d-md-down-none" style="width:44%">
                <div class="card-body text-center">
                    <div>
                        <h2>Sistema de Ventas</h2>
                        <p>Sistema de compras, Ventas desarrollado en PHP utilizando el Framework Laravel y Vue
                            Js, con el gestor de base de datos MariaDB.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

archivo controlador **loginController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;


class LoginController extends Controller
{
   public function showLoginForm(){
       return view('auth.login');
   }

   public function login(Request $request){
      $this->validateLogin($request);

        // se valida si son los datos ingresados y que los usuarios esten activos.
       if(Auth::attempt(['usuario'=>$request->usuario,'password'=>$request->password,'condicion'=>1])){
          return redirect()->route('main');
       }
       //si no es un usuario lo regresa al principio con los errores correspondientes
       return back()
       ->withErrors(['usuario'=>trans('auth.failed')])
       ->withInput(request(['usuario']));
   }

   protected function validateLogin(Request $request){
       $this->validate($request,
    [
        //validamos los datos requeridos
        'usuario'  => 'required|string',
        'password' => 'required|string',
    ]);

   }
   public function logout(Request $request){
       Auth::logout();
       $request->session()->invalidate();
       return redirect('/');
   }
}
```

archivo de las rutas **web.php**

```
<?php

//ruta en grupo con middleware para invitado
Route::group(['middleware' => ['guest']], function () {

//ruta formulario de logeo
    Route::get('/', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm');
    Route::post('/login', 'Auth\LoginController@Login')->name('login');

});
//grupo de rutas para las usuarios que tengan acceso
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {

    Route::post('/logout','Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');

//ruta principal(raiz)
    Route::get('/main', function () {
        return view('contenido/contenido');
    })->name('main');

    Route::group(['middleware' => ['Almacenero']], function () {

        Route::get('/categoria', 'CategoriaController@index');
        Route::post('/categoria/registrar', 'CategoriaController@store');
        Route::put('/categoria/actualizar', 'CategoriaController@update');
        Route::put('/categoria/desactivar', 'CategoriaController@desactivar');
        Route::put('/categoria/activar', 'CategoriaController@activar');
        Route::get('/categoria/selectCategoria', 'CategoriaController@selectCategoria');

        Route::get('/articulo', 'ArticuloController@index');
        Route::post('/articulo/registrar', 'ArticuloController@store');
        Route::put('/articulo/actualizar', 'ArticuloController@update');
        Route::put('/articulo/desactivar', 'ArticuloController@desactivar');
        Route::put('/articulo/activar', 'ArticuloController@activar');

        Route::get('/proveedor', 'ProveedorController@index');
        Route::post('/proveedor/registrar', 'ProveedorController@store');
        Route::put('/proveedor/actualizar', 'ProveedorController@update');

    });

    Route::group(['middleware' => ['Vendedor']], function () {

        Route::get('/cliente', 'ClienteController@index');
        Route::post('/cliente/registrar', 'ClienteController@store');
        Route::put('/cliente/actualizar', 'ClienteController@update');

    });

    Route::group(['middleware' => ['Administrador']], function () {

        Route::get('/categoria', 'CategoriaController@index');
        Route::post('/categoria/registrar', 'CategoriaController@store');
        Route::put('/categoria/actualizar', 'CategoriaController@update');
        Route::put('/categoria/desactivar', 'CategoriaController@desactivar');
        Route::put('/categoria/activar', 'CategoriaController@activar');
        Route::get('/categoria/selectCategoria', 'CategoriaController@selectCategoria');

        Route::get('/articulo', 'ArticuloController@index');
        Route::post('/articulo/registrar', 'ArticuloController@store');
        Route::put('/articulo/actualizar', 'ArticuloController@update');
        Route::put('/articulo/desactivar', 'ArticuloController@desactivar');
        Route::put('/articulo/activar', 'ArticuloController@activar');

        Route::get('/proveedor', 'ProveedorController@index');
        Route::post('/proveedor/registrar', 'ProveedorController@store');
        Route::put('/proveedor/actualizar', 'ProveedorController@update');

        Route::get('/cliente', 'ClienteController@index');
        Route::post('/cliente/registrar', 'ClienteController@store');
        Route::put('/cliente/actualizar', 'ClienteController@update');

        Route::get('/rol', 'RolController@index');
        Route::get('/rol/selectRol', 'RolController@selectRol');

        Route::get('/user', 'UserController@index');
        Route::post('/user/registrar', 'UserController@store');
        Route::put('/user/actualizar', 'UserController@update');
        Route::put('/user/desactivar', 'UserController@desactivar');
        Route::put('/user/activar', 'UserController@activar');

    });

});
```

Esta es la BD:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

por ultimo el archivo donde registro los middleware despues de haberlos ejecutado en artisan **kernel.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{

    protected $middleware = [
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
    ];

    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings',
        ],
    ];

    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        //se registran los middleware
        'Administrador' => \App\Http\Middleware\Administrador::class,
        'Vendedor' => \App\Http\Middleware\Vendedor::class,
        'Almacenero' => \App\Http\Middleware\Almacenero::class

    ];
}
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es la versión de Laravel?
¿Cómo sabes que ingresas la contraseña almacenada en base de datos?

Comment: La version de laravel es: 5.6. Pues obvio es la que tengo registrada en la tabla  users de la BD

Comment: La contraseña en BD está encriptada?

Comment: No esta encriptada

Answer (score 0):

Encriptala con bcrypt para que pueda hacer el match en el login.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Esto parece relamente un comentario mas que una respuesta. Con un poco mas de reputación, [vas a poder comentar en cualquier lado.](//es.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por favor mira [answer]

Comment: Si esta encriptada.